# React Formik post specific fields

Tags: reactjs, axios, formik

I'm new to both react and formik and I want to post a json object using axios. The Formik form contains all the fields and a verify password field. I don't want to store the data of verify password to the database so I was wondering how can I post the rest of the relevant fields without this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `handleSubmit`/`onSubmit`, you can compose the request data by filtering out the unwanted fields.

```js
handleSubmit: (values, formikBag) => {
 // Here I am using ES6 rest operator to filter the fields
 const { verifyPassword, ...requestData } = values;
 
 formikBag.props.formSubmitAction(requestData);
}
```